# Evaluate the integral $\int_{\left | z \right |=3} (e^{z}-1)dz/(z(z-1)(z-i))$

Tags: complex-analysis

> I want to evaluate the integral $$\int_{\left | z \right |=3} \frac{e^{z}-1}{z(z-1)(z-i)}\,dz$$ 
>   by using the following  theorem:
>
> If a function $f$ is analytic everywhere in the finite plane except for a finite number of singularities interior to a positively oriented simple closed curve $C$, then 
>   $$\int_{C}f(z) dz=2\pi i\text{Res}\left ( \frac{1}{z^{2}}f(\frac{1}{z}), 0 \right ).$$

Since $$\frac{1}{z^{2}}f(\frac{1}{z})=\frac{1+\frac{1}{2!z}+\frac{1}{3!z^{2}}\cdot \cdot \cdot }{1-(1+i)z+iz^{2}},$$ 
so I did long division, but the coefficient of 1/z(the residue of $\frac{1}{z^{2}}f(\frac{1}{z})$) is $0$. 
I know the method of calculating the residues at each singularities $0$, $1$, $i$, respectively. This method gives me the answer $2\pi i(0+\frac{e-1}{1-i}+\frac{e^{i}-1}{i(i-1)})$ which is not $0$.

Why answers are different?? Why does not hold long division method? Any help please.

Comment: It is extremely cumbersome to do so. I don’t think it’s a good idea to proceed in this direction.

Comment: What happened to this question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2812219/calculate-int-left-z-right-3-ez-1dz-zz-1z-i

Comment: Why did you post this question twice? Please delete this question. I will replicate my answer  below the first question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2812219/calculate-int-left-z-right-3-ez-1dz-zz-1z-i.